# How would you total the values in one column and keep a distinct value in another?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table that has multiple codes in one column that correspond to certain values in another column. For example, a particular code in column A corresponds to a value in column B. There are thousands of duplicate entries in column A that correspond to different values in column B. I want to add up all of the values in column B that have the particular code in column A, while only keeping one copy of the code from column A. You may think of the columns as key-value pairs, where column A contains the key and column B contains the value.

Basically, I want to add all the values in column B where column A is a specific value, and I want to do for this all of the unique "keys" in column A. I'm sure that this is a simple task; however, I am pretty new to SQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Here is the result I'm looking for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2omWu.png)

[image: 1]

Comment: Please add Sample data and expected result

Comment: Yes, edit this question and show the actual column names, but FAKE data if it is so confidential.  Use spaces to align sample data not tabs.  Also show what you Expect the results to show.

Comment: I believe you need `Group by` and `SUM` aggregate

Comment: I have updated the question with an image that should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
   A,
   SUM(B) AS sum_b
FROM [yourTable]
GROUP BY A
```

Comment: This works. Thank you! Would you happen to know why some of the results have floating-point answers when all of the values in column B are integers? Is that something that SQL Server does when a result is too big to be contained in the 'Integer' data type?

Comment: The resulting datatype of the sum will have to do with the datatype of the column - not necessarily the contents (For example, you could have a float or decimal column that happens to have all integers).  If the result was too big for the int datatype, you would see an overflow error, not a differently-typed value.  If this is a concern, you could convert the value to integer before summing, something like: SUM(CONVERT(int, B))

Comment: Ah, very nice. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COLUMNA, SUM(ISNULL(COLUMNB,0)) AS TOTAL
FROM
    dbo.TableName
GROUP BY COLUMNA
```